# Not able to fetch data besides <Strong> tag in Robot Framework

Tags: xpath, robotframework

I am trying to fetch the numeric value after `strong` tag, as its not an web element, I am not able to get the value `123456789` in to variable:
If I use Get Text `xpath=//*[@id='referral-or-navinet-reference-number']` then the result is "**Referral #: 123456789**"
Please help me in getting only numeric value in to variable.

HTML Code:

```
<td class="normal-text" id="referral-or-navinet-reference-number" align="right">
    <strong>Referral #:</strong> 123456789
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use `split` method of python

Like :-

`x.split(":")` // x is a string variable of your gettext

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm

http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-split

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks Shubham, I tried with Split String from right keyword and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If your `td` only contains the wanted text as content text you may use the following xpath:

```
//*[@id='referral-or-navinet-reference-number']/text()
```

This should return 123456789 (perhaps with some whitespace)

Answer (score 0):

You can use given xpath :

//td[@id="referral-or-navinet-reference-number"]/text()[normalize-space()]